# How to bind query params to named router view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, query-string

```
path: '/register',
name: 'Register',
components: {
  loginView: () =>
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "register" */ '../views/Register.vue'),
},
meta: { guest: true },
// props: { loginView: true },
// how to pass query params to custom router views? this is not working
props: route => ({
  email: route.query.email,
  token: route.query.token,
}),
```

How to pass query params to named router view? Using function form as here does not work for named router views. Object form works (commented out one), but that will not map query params to props, only params.

Comment: How are you calling this route? Im sorry I don't understand what you're trying to acieve. When defining a route, you don't need to define or get the query params. They are only present when a route is called or activated.

Comment: Can you post your `loginView` component -and- the URL you are trying?

Comment: I have found out an answer and posted below, with additional info that you guys requested. If you have further question I would be happy to answer, maybe I'm still missing some important info.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer on discord:

```
props: {
  loginView: route => ({
    email: route.query.email,
    token: route.query.token
  })
}
```

Basically, if you are using `components` (object form) instead of `component` (function form), you need to provide props in same way.

For the completeness I was calling this route: `http://localhost:8000/register?token=3424234&email=some@email.com`, and loginView is just named router view (`<RouterView name="loginView" />`).